# How do deal with React hooks returning stale event handlers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with stale event handlers returned by a hook. First when the component is first rendered, it makes a an asynchronous request to api to fetch credentials. Then these credentials are used when pressing a submit button in a dialog to create a resource. The problem is the credentials for the dialog submit button click event handler are undefined even after the credentials have been fetched.

credentials.js

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { api } from './api';

export const useCredentials = (setCredentials) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncGetCredentials = async () => {
      const result = await api.getCredentials();
      if (result) {
        setCredentials(result);
      }
    };
    asyncGetCredentials().then();
  }, []);

  return credentials;
}
```

useComponent.js

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useCredentials } from './credentials';
import { createResource } from './resources';
import { useDialog } from './useDialog';

export const useComponent = () => {
  const { closeDialog } = useDialog();
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState();
  useCredentials(setCredentials);

  const credentialsRef = useRef(credentials);

  useEffect(() => {
    // logs credentials properly after they have been fetched
    console.log(credentials) 
    credentialsRef.current = credentials;
  }, [credentials]);

  const createResourceUsingCredentials = useCallback(
    async function () {
      // credentials and credentialsRef.current are both undefined
      // even when the function is called after the credentials
      // have already been fetched.
      console.log(credentials);
      console.log(credentialsRef.current);

      createResource(credentialsRef.current); 
    }, [credentials, credentialsRef, credentialsRef.current]
  );

  const onDialogSubmit = useCallback(
    async function () {
      await createResourceUsingCredentials();
      closeDialog();
    }, [
      credentials,
      credentialsRef,
      credentialsRef.current,
      createResourceUsingCredentials,
    ],
  );

  return {
    onDialogSubmit,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was in the useCredentials hook implementation. It blocks any further requests for credentials to the api if a request is already in flight. Due to poor implementation of this functionality, if more than 1 component using that hook was rendered, only the component that was rendered first got updated credentials. I changed the useCredentials hooks so that it subscribes to the global state (that has the credentials) so that no matter which component starts the request, all components will get the credentials when the request finishes. https://simbathesailor007.medium.com/debug-your-reactjs-hooks-with-ease-159691843c3a helped a lot with debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
export const useCredentials = (setCredentials) => { 

  useEffect(() => {
    const asyncGetCredentials = async () => {
      const result = await api.getCredentials();
      if (result) {
        setCredentials(result);
      }
    };
    asyncGetCredentials().then();
  }, []); 
}


export const useComponent = () => {
  const { closeDialog } = useDialog();
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState(); // new add
  useCredentials(setCredentials); 

  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nooruddin, I have edited the code in the question according to your recommendation, but I still get stale undefined values in the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding complexity, always return function and check inside the function for  `credentials`

```
export const useComponent = () => {
    const { closeDialog } = useDialog();
    const credentials = useCredentials();

    // correctly logs undefined at first and updated credentials
    // when they are asynchronously received from the api.
    console.log(credentials);

    async function createResourceUsingCredentials() {
        createResource(credentials);
    }

    let onClickDialogSubmit = async () => {
        if (credentials) {
            await createResourceUsingCredentials();
            closeDialog();
        }
    };

    return {
        onClickDialogSubmit,
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm adding complexity to get around the stale closure problem. Your solution doesn't work.